# Android Tango HAL

Tags: google-project-tango

I am wondering where I can find documents regarding Tango HAL to send sensor data (Depth, color image and IMU) from our developing AR glasses into Android Tango or where I can find the ENG support from Google.

Comment: If you are building tango-enabled AR glasses I think you should contact the project tango team directly instead of asking here. Try to reach Johnny C. Lee on Linkedin, on his blog, on G+, etc.

Comment: Appreciate  your sharing. I did left Johnny Lee the message to get ENG support on LinkedIn, but no response. I guess Johnny is too busy or there should other contact windows. If you have any possible contact windows, please kindly share me.